# Que algoritmo usar para um mecanismo de diff?

Tags: algoritmo, versionamento

Sabe esse mecanismos de *difference* de conteúdo que usamos em controle de versões variadas, onde [pode ser visto na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Harbour_%28software%29&type=revision&diff=355096377&oldid=354022155) ou [no Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/32326/files), [até mesmo aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/15698/3)?

Assim como existem algoritmos conhecidos como o [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) que pegam números aleatórios sem repetição de forma eficiente sob certas circunstâncias, acredito que exista um ou mais algoritmos consagrados para fazer o diferencial de conteúdo. Estou certo? Qual seria o algoritmo que pega dois conteúdos e os compara indicando as diferenças entre eles? Ou quais seriam.

Note que só quero qual é, e claro, alguma descrição dele, não é necessário uma implementação.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, isso é feito encontrando a [Subsequência Comum Mais Longa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) (também chamada de *LCS problem*). O algoritmo específico usado pelo `diff` e pela maioria das outras ferramentas de comparação é o [Algoritmo de Diferença O(ND) de Eugene Myer](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=96223) e outras variações.